# jQuery Cycle permalinks not working, always goes to first slide

Tags: jquery, anchor, cycle, permalinks

I've got Cycle generating anchorlinks, which work fine within the slideshow page. However, linking to them from another page doesn't quite work. They always go to the first slide of the group, instead of the slide defined by the url hash. Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
$('#cms').cycle({
    fx:  'fade',
    speed:  'fast',
    pager:  '#nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#' + slide.title + '">' + slide.title + '</a></li>';
    }, 
    timeout: 0,
    after: function(curr,next,opts) {
        window.location.hash =  $(this).attr('title');
    }
    });
});
```

and the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="cms">  
<div title="About"><?php include 'about.php' ?></div>
<div title="Music"><?php include 'music.php' ?></div>
<div title="Shows"><?php include 'shows.php' ?></div>
</div>
```

Basically, if I link to (or open up a new browser tab and enter) "http://path/to/my/page/#Music", or #Shows, it just goes to #About.

I know I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure what

Answer (score 0):

Malsup posted an answer in the [jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/malsup-cycle-restarts-goto-doesn-t-work) that might be the problem.  Most of the 'goto' type functionality is not supported by cycle lite.  You have to have the full plugin.